# AngularJS: How to pass variable to controller function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, components

There is my component

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("application_module")
        .component('tab', {
            controller: 'TabCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/component/application/app-header/tab/tab.html',
            bindings: {
                'pagename': '<',
                'pageno': '<'
            },
            require: {
                "parent": "^appHeader"
            }
        });
})();
```

There is my child controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("application_module")
        .controller('TabCtrl', TabCtrl);

    function TabCtrl() {
        let self = this;
    }

})();
```

Here is parent controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("application_module")
        .controller('AppHeaderCtrl', AppHeaderCtrl);

    function AppHeaderCtrl(commonServiceAuth) {
        let self = this;
        Object.assign(self, commonServiceAuth);

        self.currentNavItem = 'page1';

        self.goto = function (page) {
            self.currentNavItem = page;
        };
    }
})();
```

And it's my html code:

```
<md-nav-item md-nav-click="$ctrl.parent.goto($ctrl.pageno)"
             name="$ctrl.pageno">
    {{$ctrl.pagename}}
</md-nav-item>
```

So my issue is that when i pass `$ctrl.pageno`, my controller sets `self.currentNavItem` to string value '$ctrl.pageno' instead of it's actual value.

Comment: you don't need to pass as $ctrl.pageno just try pageno but where is pageno binded as a model ? there is no traces of ur component being used

Comment: @VinodLouis mybe he is using controller as syntax

Comment: he must be missing that controllerAs syntax then to get this error

Comment: You are not using controllerAs syntax in your component and using $ctrl.something in your HTML template for that component.

Comment: what do you have in `$ctrl.pageno` actually?